# Why does this stored procedure give a different result from executing its contents manually?

Tags: mysql

Here's a simple MySQL schema

```
CREATE TABLE Currency
(
     id          SMALLINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
    ,code        CHAR(3) NOT NULL UNIQUE
    ,exponent    TINYINT NOT NULL
    ,sign        VARCHAR (5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '¤'
    ,ccx_enabled BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT FALSE
    ,is_fiat     BOOLEAN NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE `SiteAccount`
(
     id          INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
    ,currency    SMALLINT NOT NULL
    ,iban        VARCHAR (34) NULL DEFAULT NULL
    ,ethereum    CHAR (40) NULL DEFAULT NULL
    ,crypto_user INT NULL DEFAULT NULL
    ,FOREIGN KEY (currency)    REFERENCES Currency (id)
);

CREATE PROCEDURE SetUpUserEthereumAddress (id INT, addr TEXT)
INSERT INTO SiteAccount (currency, ethereum, crypto_user)
VALUES
(
    (SELECT id FROM Currency WHERE code='ETH'),
    addr,
    id
);
```

If I call the stored procedure, it creates a row with the wrong currency.

```
INSERT INTO Currency (code, exponent, sign, is_fiat, ccx_enabled) VALUES
     ('GBP', 2, '£', 1, 1)
    ,('USD', 2, '$', 1, 1)
    ,('EUR', 2, '€', 1, 1)
    ,('ETH', 6, 'Ξ', 0, 1)
;

CALL SetUpUserEthereumAddress (1, '5bb0aa60d694714db16cbd3e3574c59d5ee4a95b');

select * from SiteAccount JOIN Currency on SiteAccount.currency=Currency.id;
```

This [creates a row](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fec258/1/0) with the currency GBP instead of ETH. But if I copy out the body of the stored procedure and substitute the arguments manually, I get the correct result.

```
INSERT INTO SiteAccount (currency, ethereum, crypto_user)
VALUES
(
    (SELECT id FROM Currency WHERE code='ETH'),
    '----aa60d694714db16cbd3e3574c59d5ee4a95b',
    2
);

select * from SiteAccount JOIN Currency on SiteAccount.currency=Currency.id;
```

This creates a record for currency ETH as expected.

Why does the stored procedure select/insert the wrong Currency id?

Comment: `SELECT id FROM Currency` -> `SELECT Currency.id FROM Currency`

Comment: Thanks, can you make that an actual answer so I can accept it?

Comment: @Jordan: only one of the values is being set from the select statement, so the syntax is correct. To use the insert using select the select statement would need to be modified to _SELECT id, '----aa60d694714db16cbd3e3574c59d5ee4a95b', 2 FROM Currency WHERE code='ETH'_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you inside stored procedure, unqualified `id` in `SELECT id FROM Currency WHERE code='ETH'` refer to stored procedure `id` parameter, but not `id` column in `Currency` table. To refer to table column you need to qualify `id` with table name: `SELECT Currency.id FROM Currency WHERE code='ETH'`.

Comment: Alternatively, changing the procedure parameter name to something other than _id_ would also get the correct result.